# Formula to auto copy and display cell if contain a specific word

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheets where I store RSS feeds (in Sheet1). What I would like to do is to create a formula that will, in Sheet2, copy and  display all feeds from Sheet1, which contain certain words. Screenshot of example:
[image: Screenshot of example]

In this example I would like to copy and display (from Sheet1 to Sheet2) all feeds with the words BLACK and SHIRT, and from here on I would like to auto copy and display feed, every time it will contain this two words.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion, but unfortunately, this is not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return rows that contain the string 'black shirt':

`=QUERY(Sheet1!B:B;"select * where B contains 'black shirt'";1)`

To return rows that contain any complete words listed in C2:C:

`=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B;MMULT(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(" "&C2:C&" ");" "&Sheet1!B2:B&" ");SIGN(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B))))`

[QUERY documentation](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882)

[FILTER documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240287)

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZdNQHjqWKqdGVrNXpZZExHc0FORW91LTVRN0ZQNVE#gid=1)

Comment: +bmargulies, do you mean that "try" is an inappropriate word? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiZdNQHjqWKqdGVrNXpZZExHc0FORW91LTVRN0ZQNVE

Comment: Just one more thing. Now I have situation where I am having two words that must be in cell which I would like to copy and display. What about if I would like to have list of words i.e. black, shirt, white, shirt etc. and I would like to copy and display cell that contain ANY of this words (black OR shirt OR white etc.)?

Comment: The second formula doesn't seem to work anymore. I copied that to my sheet and it returns a matrix error with `MMULT`. With `MMULT.LEGACY` it won't find any results.

The example spreadsheet still works, however it works on what's on screen now but it doesn't if I clone it onto another sheet and change all the data of `Sheet1!B2:B` it stops working. Is there something that can be done?