# Google Spreadsheet Query formula- show row below matching result

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm wondering if it's possible to adapt this formula and use query function to display the row *below* the one that matches the query?

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B:B;"select * where B contains 'black shirt'";1)
```

[Google Docs formula auto copy and display cell if contain a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126129/google-docs-formula-auto-copy-and-display-cell-if-contain-a-specific-word)

I'm importing data and the row I want to extract is always preceded by a unique row that I can search for.

Comment: Index() and match() would be a better candidate I guess: =index(B:B, match("black shirt",B:B,0)+1) But that will only work if you want to extract one row.

Comment: If you need to extract more than one row you could try; =ArrayFormula(vlookup(FILTER(row(B:B)+1, "black shirt"=B:B), {row(B:B),B:B}, 2, 0))

Comment: Brilliant- index and match do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Seems like this solves it:

=index(B:B, match("black shirt",B:B,0)+1)